# Assigning and calling Object properties inside another object

Tags: c#, class, properties, instance, getter-setter

I have an requirement of creating sub properties in side an object like below(highlighted),
And I would like to do it in one go like below. Other than creating separate object and attaching it to main object.

But it is not assigning the value , pls help.

```
   Test oTest=new oTest();
    oTest.Prop1=100;
    ***oTest.Sub.SubProp3="10";***
```

Classes are defined like below,

```
public  class Test 
{
    public int Prop1{ get; set; }
    public int Prop2{ get; set; }

    private Subtest _sub = null;

    public Subtest Sub {
        get
        {
            return (_sub != null) ? _sub : new Subtest();
        }
        set {  
            _sub = value; 
        }
    }
  }

    public class Subtest
            {
              public int SubProp1{ get; set; }
              public int SubProp2{ get; set; }

              private string _SubProp3;

              public string SubProp3
              {
                get { return _SubProp3; }
                set { _SubProp3= value; }
              }
            }
```

Comment: "But it is not assigning the value" really, because I would expect the code to crash with a NullRefrenceException, not just not get assigned. Do you have this code in a try-catch block where you are throwing away the exceptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of options:

- Change your field initializer:

  ```
  private Subtest _sub = new Subtest();
  ```
- Set a new value at construction:

  ```
  public Test()
  {
      _sub = new Subtest();
  }
  ```
- Set a new value when getting:

  ```
  public Subtest Sub {
      get
      {
          if(_sub == null)
              _sub = new Subtest();
          return _sub;
      }
      set {  
          _sub = value; 
      }
  }
  ```

The main benefit of the third option is the creation of the sub-item is delayed until the property is retrieved.  The downside is that getters with side-effects can be problematic.

Comment: I prefer the last option but it will not set  oTest.SubProp.SubProp3=10 . it is null always. ??

Comment: I don't see a property `SubProp` in your definition.  In fact your sample code and usage have several disconnects (`Subprop3` is a string, not an int, etc.).

Comment: sorry i have corrected it pls. check. it should be , oTest.Sub.SubProp3="10"

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @ DStanley to simplify you can simply

```
    public Subtest Sub {
get
{
   return _sub ?? (_sub = new Subtest());
}
set {  
    _sub = value; 
}
```

}

Comment: my real prob is setting value for prop3 in subtest object , like below oTest.Sub.SubProp3="10". which is still null

Comment: Just do the same thing for prop3 as soon as you try to call the SubTest it will instantiate it and then when you call prop it too will be instantiated. so even if you do test.Subtest.Prop it will be available

Comment: Just to explain further that would mean that prop3 would be public Prop3{get {return _prop3 ?? (prop3 = "");}}